# spaCy produces "PicklingError: Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required." after the first run (second run onwards)

Tags: python-3.x, spyder, spacy

I currently work on spaCy on Spyder3 editor.

But after the first run of below simple code. It gives me the error

```
"PicklingError: Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required."
```

Could you help me resolve the issue? Am I missing any additional code or settings?

Thanks,

Saul

I could run the code with no issue on jupyter notebook, but it fails on Spyder3.

```
import spacy

nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

It should run without any error.

I have already installed 'en_core_web_sm'

I am not sure what the problem is.

please find whole error message below.

```
Reloaded modules: __mp_main__, spacy, thinc, thinc.about, thinc.neural, thinc.neural._classes, thinc.neural._classes.model, srsly, srsly._json_api, srsly.ujson, srsly.ujson.ujson, srsly.util, srsly._msgpack_api, srsly.msgpack, srsly.msgpack._version, srsly.msgpack.exceptions, srsly.msgpack._packer, srsly.msgpack._unpacker, srsly.msgpack._ext_type, srsly.msgpack._msgpack_numpy, srsly._pickle_api, srsly.cloudpickle, srsly.cloudpickle.cloudpickle, thinc.neural.util, thinc.neural.train, tqdm, tqdm._tqdm, tqdm._utils, tqdm._monitor, tqdm._tqdm_gui, tqdm._tqdm_pandas, tqdm._main, tqdm._version, thinc.neural.optimizers, thinc.neural.ops, thinc.neural.mem, thinc.check, thinc.compat, thinc.extra, thinc.extra.wrapt, thinc.extra.wrapt.wrappers, thinc.extra.wrapt._wrappers, thinc.extra.wrapt.decorators, thinc.extra.wrapt.importer, thinc.exceptions, wasabi, wasabi.printer, wasabi.tables, wasabi.util, wasabi.traceback, spacy.cli, spacy.cli.download, plac, plac_core, plac_ext, spacy.cli.link, spacy.compat, spacy.util, pkg_resources, pkg_resources.extern, pkg_resources._vendor, pkg_resources.extern.six, pkg_resources.py31compat, pkg_resources.extern.appdirs, pkg_resources._vendor.packaging.__about__, pkg_resources.extern.packaging, pkg_resources.extern.packaging.version, pkg_resources.extern.packaging._structures, pkg_resources.extern.packaging.specifiers, pkg_resources.extern.packaging._compat, pkg_resources.extern.packaging.requirements, pkg_resources.extern.pyparsing, pkg_resources.extern.packaging.markers, jsonschema, jsonschema.exceptions, attr, attr.converters, attr._make, attr._config, attr._compat, attr.exceptions, attr.filters, attr.validators, attr._funcs, jsonschema._utils, jsonschema.compat, jsonschema._format, jsonschema._types, pyrsistent, pyrsistent._pmap, pyrsistent._compat, pyrsistent._pvector, pyrsistent._transformations, pvectorc, pyrsistent._pset, pyrsistent._pbag, pyrsistent._plist, pyrsistent._pdeque, pyrsistent._checked_types, pyrsistent._field_common, pyrsistent._precord, pyrsistent._pclass, pyrsistent._immutable, pyrsistent._helpers, pyrsistent._toolz, jsonschema.validators, jsonschema._legacy_validators, jsonschema._validators, spacy.symbols, spacy.errors, spacy.about, spacy.cli.info, spacy.cli.package, spacy.cli.profile, thinc.extra.datasets, thinc.extra._vendorized, thinc.extra._vendorized.keras_data_utils, thinc.extra._vendorized.keras_generic_utils, spacy.cli.train, spacy._ml, thinc.v2v, thinc.neural._classes.affine, thinc.describe, thinc.neural._classes.relu, thinc.neural._classes.maxout, thinc.neural._classes.softmax, thinc.neural._classes.selu, thinc.i2v, thinc.neural._classes.hash_embed, thinc.neural._lsuv, thinc.neural._classes.embed, thinc.neural._classes.static_vectors, thinc.extra.load_nlp, thinc.t2t, thinc.neural._classes.convolution, thinc.neural._classes.attention, thinc.neural._classes.rnn, thinc.api, thinc.neural._classes.function_layer, thinc.neural._classes.feed_forward, thinc.t2v, thinc.neural.pooling, thinc.misc, thinc.neural._classes.batchnorm, thinc.neural._classes.layernorm, thinc.neural._classes.resnet, thinc.neural._classes.feature_extracter, thinc.linear, thinc.linear.linear, spacy.attrs, spacy.gold, spacy.cli.pretrain, spacy.tokens, spacy.tokens.doc, spacy.tokens.token, spacy.tokens.span, spacy.cli.debug_data, spacy.cli.evaluate, spacy.displacy, spacy.displacy.render, spacy.displacy.templates, spacy.cli.convert, spacy.cli.converters, spacy.cli.converters.conllu2json, spacy.cli.converters.iob2json, spacy.cli.converters.conll_ner2json, spacy.cli.converters.jsonl2json, spacy.cli.init_model, preshed, preshed.about, preshed.counter, spacy.vectors, spacy.cli.validate, spacy.glossary
Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "<ipython-input-5-e0e768bc0aee>", line 1, in <module>
    runfile('/home/saul/pythontraining/NLP/itemWork_3.py', wdir='/home/saul/pythontraining/NLP')

  File "/home/saul/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 786, in runfile
    execfile(filename, namespace)

  File "/home/saul/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spyder_kernels/customize/spydercustomize.py", line 110, in execfile
    exec(compile(f.read(), filename, 'exec'), namespace)

  File "/home/saul/pythontraining/NLP/itemWork_3.py", line 11, in <module>
    nlp = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/__init__.py", line 27, in load
    return util.load_model(name, **overrides)

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 131, in load_model
    return load_model_from_package(name, **overrides)

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 152, in load_model_from_package
    return cls.load(**overrides)

  File "/home/saul/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/site-packages/en_core_web_sm/__init__.py", line 12, in load
    return load_model_from_init_py(__file__, **overrides)

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 190, in load_model_from_init_py
    return load_model_from_path(data_path, meta, **overrides)

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 173, in load_model_from_path
    return nlp.from_disk(model_path)

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 791, in from_disk
    util.from_disk(path, deserializers, exclude)

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 630, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/language.py", line 787, in <lambda>
    deserializers[name] = lambda p, proc=proc: proc.from_disk(p, exclude=["vocab"])

  File "pipes.pyx", line 617, in spacy.pipeline.pipes.Tagger.from_disk

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/util.py", line 630, in from_disk
    reader(path / key)

  File "pipes.pyx", line 599, in spacy.pipeline.pipes.Tagger.from_disk.load_model

  File "pipes.pyx", line 512, in spacy.pipeline.pipes.Tagger.Model

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/_ml.py", line 513, in build_tagger_model
    pretrained_vectors=pretrained_vectors,

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/spacy/_ml.py", line 363, in Tok2Vec
    embed >> convolution ** conv_depth, pad=conv_depth

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/check.py", line 131, in checker
    return wrapped(*args, **kwargs)

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 281, in __pow__
    return self._operators["**"](self, other)

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/api.py", line 117, in clone
    layers.append(copy.deepcopy(orig))

  File "/home/saul/anaconda3/lib/python3.7/copy.py", line 169, in deepcopy
    rv = reductor(4)

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/thinc/neural/_classes/model.py", line 96, in __getstate__
    return srsly.pickle_dumps(self.__dict__)

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/srsly/_pickle_api.py", line 14, in pickle_dumps
    return cloudpickle.dumps(data, protocol=protocol)

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/srsly/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 954, in dumps
    cp.dump(obj)

  File "/home/saul/.local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/srsly/cloudpickle/cloudpickle.py", line 288, in dump
    raise pickle.PicklingError(msg)

PicklingError: Could not pickle object as excessively deep recursion required.
```

Comment: PicklingError is a writing error. You instead showed us code that reads (that `load`s). Show us the code that actually fails. Be sure to match the line number in the exception trace to the lines of code you post in the edited question.

Comment: Hi J_H, I added the error log. The issue looks like in the Python SpaCy built-in modules.

Answer (score 0):

Yup, sure enough, your read operation is attempting
a failed write operation (serialization) behind the scenes,
most curious.

What you are attempting is absolutely vanilla,
and comes straight from [the docs](https://spacy.io/usage/models).
It certainly *should* work.

Sorry, but I can't reproduce this on my Mac.
I used conda 4.7.5 to install spacy 2.0.12
(`conda install spacy`),
which brought in thinc 6.10.3 as a dep.
From where Tok2Vec appears in the stack trace line numbers,
it is clear to me that you are running some different version.

Once I've asked spacy to download it,
`spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')` works flawlessly.

Your call stack goes from spacy to thinc to [srsly](https://pypi.org/project/srsly/).
I do not have srsly installed.
If I `pip install srsly` it pulls in 0.0.7,
and has no effect on subsequent successful `spacy.load()`
operations.

Recommend wiping your environment and doing a clean
`conda install spacy`, there's a fair chance that
will remedy the situation.

## versionitis

The thinc [rel notes](https://github.com/explosion/thinc/releases/) point out this change in 7.0.0:

> Use srsly for serialization.

Asking conda to install downrev spacy,
or to downrev one of those two deps,
may change the srsly interaction
and hence change your symptom.

Once you better understand the situation,
perhaps by seeing a successful `.load()`,
you may want to file a bug report against an affected project.